# Liquibase - Spring Boot - DATABASECHANGELOG creation failing

Tags: spring-boot, sybase, liquibase

I am using liquibase with spring boot for Sybase ASE and on application start I am getting this error -

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Permission denied, database db_local, owner dbo. You need the following permission(s) to run this command: CREATE TABLE
```

This is perhaps because we are using different credentials for login but for executing the change sets we have defined to set proxy to another user having all permissions like this -

```
  <changeSet author="12345" id="set-dbo-alias" runAlways="true" dbms="sybase">
    <comment> This should run always as the first step </comment>
    <sql>SET quoted_identifier OFF</sql>
    <sql>set proxy dbMainUser</sql>
    <sql>set replication off</sql>
  </changeSet>
```

However, on start up it is trying to create the DATABASECHANGELOG table and this seems to be happening before executing the change set where I am setting the proxy. I don't know how do I set the proxy to dbMainUser. Any suggestions or guidance would help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Liquibase creates the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK and DATABASECHANGELOG tables as a very first step -- prior to knowing what to run or what to not run from the changelog table.

There is currently no way to specify "setup sql" out of the box.

If your java skills are up to it, you could create an extension based of the SybaseDatabase class that overrides the setConnection() method and calls whatever custom SQL you need on the connection at that point.

Otherwise, if you manually create the DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK tables, Liquibase will use them instead of trying to re-create them. The non-proxy user will need permissions to insert/update into those tables, though.

Comment: I created https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2008 to track the feature request of "want to run custom SQL at connection time"